# Howto integrate jruby integration tests into a maven build?

Tags: java, testing, jruby, maven-3, integration-testing

Currently I work on a java web application that is build with maven 3. The integration tests for the application are written in ruby using `minitest` and `capybara`. Currently I use `c-ruby` and `bundler` to run the tests. For Jenkins integration we use the `ci_reporter` gem and a rake task.

I want to integrate the testing with the maven lifecycle. For this I use the `cargo-maven2-plugin` to start and stop an application server in the `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phase. What i am trying to achieve is to run the ruby integration tests in the `integration-test` phase.

What is the best way to add dependencies? Is it possible to use `bundler`?

How to start the tests using jruby?

Comment: Have you tried to just invoke the rake task?